# resize images according to window size

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, resize

How can i resize images in [this example](http://www.sanders-albek.nl/bm.html)  ? I want the images resize with the proper aspect ratio when I resize the window.

Should this be done with jquery or with html/css?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using jquery you can use the resize method

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  // check the window width and resize your images
  var width = $(window).width();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A Simple search on google provides the answer.

Use JQuery Vegas to have full size fading. http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/

Use Supersized to have full size sliding. http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

Comment: Thanks fr your reply. But this is going to be a gallery, and there will be more images when you scroll horizontaly. Do you have experience with the plugin? Will it work properly then?

Comment: Edited my answer to include sliding.

Comment: still not exactly what i am looking for. I want the pictures to appear on the page like it is now, only when the window resizes it should resize.